# Renderizar PartialViews diferentes de forma aleatória

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Eu tenho o seguinte cenário: tenho que passar para uma `view` dados de tabelas diferentes (dados parecidos, porem sem relação alguma), até ai consegui de boa. Criei uma classe(viewmodel) que recebe os dados, no `Controller` alimento ela quando vou dar o retorno para a view, e na `view` dou um foreach em cada propriedade e dentro desse foreach renderizo as `PartialView` respectivas. Até ai tudo certo.

Porém, tenho a intenção de "misturar" essas `partialView`, e não mostrar primeiro os dados de uma propriedade e depois que acabar todos, ir para outra.

Como exibiria isso de uma forma "aleatória"? Ou melhor, qual a lógica para exibir algo "aleatório"? Seria algum laço for?

*Para maior entendimento, segue os `ViewModel`, `Controller` e `View`:*

**ViewModel**

```
public class VideosManuaisIndex
{
    public IEnumerable<Video> Videos { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Manual> Manuais { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new VideosManuaisIndex 
    { 
         Videos = db.Video.ToList().OrderBy(v => v.sistema),
         Manuais = db.Manual.ToList().OrderBy(m => m.sistema)
    });
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="vid-lista">
@foreach (var manual in Model.Manuais)
{
    @Html.Partial("_Manual", manual);
}

@foreach (var video in Model.Videos)
{
    @Html.Partial("_Video", video)
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bem, você poderia criar um *For Loop*, e ir verificando se os valores são nulos, não sei se é ortodoxo mas ficaria algo como:

```
@{

    var length = Model.Manuais.Count > Model.Videos.Count ? Model.Manuais.Count : Model.Videos.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(Model.Manuais[i] != null)
        {
            Html.Partial("_Manual", Model.Manuais[i]);
        }

        if (Model.Videos[i] != null)
        {
            Html.Partial("_Video", Model.Videos[i]);
        }
    }
}
```